# Cloing a form and keep Jquery Validation working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the `clone` method to keep a copy of a form as it should be when the page is first loaded. I do this so that I can easily "reset" the form back to it's original state.

I am also using `JQuery Validation` on this form which is started on document ready. My problem is that when I replace the form with the clone, the `JQuery Validation` set's itself up with default settings.

I'm guessing because I clone the form, the events/data etc that it attached to the form are no longer available, so JQuery reattaches to the form, but with the default values.

I can fix this by calling the `validate` function everytime I clone the form, however is there a way to clone the form correctly that the validation will still work?

I've tried:

```
var original = $("form").clone(true);
var placeholder $("form").parent();
$("form").detach();
placeholder.after(original.clone(true);
```

However this doesn't work.

Comment: And the reason why `$("form").get(0).reset()` doesn't work is ...?

Comment: Because `reset` doesn't work on all elements. I have custom plugins such as `bootstrap tags`, `chosen`, `select2` and custom switches which are not reset.